# Get issue details for failed fetch() requests

Tags: javascript, fetch, typeerror

I have a page that sends requests to API server using fetch(). The server is located on a different address and there are often some network issues. In order to help a user to resolve such issues faster, I would like to receive about a caused issue as much information as possible. I've googled a lot without any luck. All that I have for all network failed requests is the message "Failed to fetch" which gives simply nothing.

I have read about handling failed requests on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch
where is written the following:

> A fetch() promise will reject with a TypeError when a network error is encountered or CORS is misconfigured on the server-side, although this usually means permission issues or similar — a 404 does not constitute a network error, for example.

In other words - there can be a different kind of error that is hidden under the error "Failed to fetch".
Is it possible somehow to retrieve the actual reason of the failure?

I'll even agree to use another interface instead of fetch() for making requests if that another interface provides more information about failed requests.

Answer (score 2):

> In other words - there can be a different kind of error that is hidden under the error "Failed to fetch". Is it possible somehow to retrieve the actual reason of the failure?

If it's a rejection from `fetch` itself, it's one of three kinds of errors:

- An error initializing the Request
- An `AbortError` because the request was aborted
- A network error (the most common reason)

You can find the details [here](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#fetch-method). It's unlikely that there's much information available other than the rejection reason's type `Error` (`TypeError`, `AbortError`, etc.)

If it's an HTTP error, then `fetch` doesn't reject the promise, it *fulfills* it with a Response object whose `ok` property will be `false` and whose `status` property will give the HTTP status code (404 or similar). You can also read the body of the error response (using the `text()` method, or `json()` if the server sends back JSON text with errors, etc.).

So at a minimum, you can differentiate between aborted requests, network errors, and HTTP errors, and with HTTP errors you can differentiate what kind it was (404, 500, etc.) and the server can (if configured to) send you more information about the error in the response body.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Actually I don't have problems with handling HTTP errors, the code already handles them. My question is about differentiation only network issues.

Comment: Thank you for the info regarding TypeError, AbortError, etc.! I'll try it.